# Cannot Stay Logged in to PhpMyAdmin after Installing SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, bitnami

After installing the SSL Cert for my domain, I can no longer stay logged in to PhpMyAdmin remotely via SSH.

Before SSL:

- PHP-based migrated to a fresh [Bitnami LAMP Stack deployed and hosted with Google Cloud Platform](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/cloud/google).
- I updated to [PMA 4.6.5.1](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.6.5.1/)
- I successfully used Putty to tunnel from http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin to http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin on the server using `local 127.0.0.1:8888 --> remote localhost:80`

After SSL:

- SSL installed via Comodo's generic Linux Apache directions [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1164/37/ssl-certificate-installation-in-apache). (`bitnami.conf` changes shown below)
- Web app is publicly accessible via https://EPHEMERAL_IP_ADDRESS/ (and redirect from http://EPHEMERAL_IP_ADDRESS/ to http://EPHEMERAL_IP_ADDRESS/)

  - Previously accessible on live server https://my.domain/ (and redirects from http://my.domain/ to https://my.domain), but I **haven't swapped IPs yet so ServerName** might be an issue?
- I added `local 127.0.0.1:8383 --> remote localhost:443` to my Putty configuration.
- **I *can* access https://127.0.0.1:8383/phpmyadmin and log in. But as soon as click anything (e.g. a database name) within PMA, I am booted out to the PMA login screen.**

Changes made to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On                                   #added
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on                          #added
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] #added
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"> 
  ...
</VirtualHost>
...
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  ServerName mydomain.com:443                          #added
  ServerAdmin my@email.address                         #added
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/my_domain.crt"          #changed
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/myserver.key"        #changed
  SSLCACertificateFile "/path/tof/my_domain.ca-bundle" #added
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Essentially**: I turned on SSL per client specification, but this has broken my PMA access. Any help is *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO's suggestion [Installing SSL certificate breaks phpmyadmin with 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746956/installing-ssl-certificate-breaks-phpmyadmin-with-403-error#comment49699449_30746956) came through for the win:

While I simply accessed PMA from a different browser, **the more commonly applicable solution is deleting the specific PMA cookies**. (HT [Isaac Bennetch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385479/isaac-bennetch))

See [here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-delete-cookies-in-chrome-firefox-safari-and-ie/) for specifics on how to delete specific cookies in various browsers.

Comment: In this case, it may have been an old cookie; you can try clearing the phpMyAdmin cookies (which start with "pma").